# changing image source with refreshing ajax variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

This function gives me `0` or `1` value in `#durum` div. Bu I want to use this value in order to show image and this image will change when the value changes.

For example if ajax gives `1` it will show `1.jpg` or if it gives `0` it will show `2.jpg`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    gonder();
    var int = self.setInterval("gonder()", 500);
});

function gonder(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'maot.php',
        success: function (msg) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(msg);
            $("#durum").html(data[0]);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="durum"></div>
```

The question is this ajax gives "0" or "1" to me I cannot use this value for getting image. Please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: it not due to ajax, if you get 0 or 1, if because you are returning that in you server, so, check your server response.

Comment: Calling something twice a second will equate to a ***lot*** of requests if you have a decent amount of users. You may want to increase that timeout.

Comment: maot.php gives "1" or "0" to ajax and #durum div. You can consider 1 as fish 2 as turtle,

so it should show fish.jpg or turtle.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code adding an image tag with an src depends on the response value. You need to ensure your server response is correct, in this case your server response must be an array [0] or [1].

```
function gonder(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'maot.php',
        success: function (msg) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(msg);
            var img = data[0] == 0 ? '1.jpg' : '2.jpg';
            $("#durum").html('<img src="'+ img +'">');    
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: this'll will work if you change it to `$("#durum").html('<img src="'+ img  +'">'); ` you don't need the '.jpg' twice

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work @Ragnar :( in chrome, what I can see is broken image picture flashes all the time.

Comment: You can check your console to see what's happening, maybe your server response is incorrect or your images are not copied in the right place.

Comment: ok it worked bro thanks, last question :)

if I want to show third image what should I change in the code? I mean 0.jpg, 1.jpg and 2.jpg @Ragnar

Comment: ast question bro :) if I want to show third image what should I change in the code? I mean 0.jpg, 1.jpg and 2.jpg @Ragnar

Comment: If your server returns the image ID instead of 1 or 0, you can have multiple images, for example if the server returns [3] or [4] or [5] you can use `$("#durum").html('<img src="'+ data[0] +'.jpg">');` for getting the ID in the first position of your array.